# How to reset the homepage of my site in Sharepoint Design?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Well, I'm beginner with Sharepoint so I do not know how to reset my site to it's initial status without web parts i.e. the default state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If versioning is enabled on your library where the file is stored, then you should be able to roll it back to version 1.0.

If versioning is not enabled, then you can try to right click on the file in SharePoint Designer and select Revert to Site Definition (or it could be labeled Reset to Site Definition, going from memory). This should make your current page a copy, and generate a new file in the default state.